# Is it possible to create rounded corners for an inserted image in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice

I imported an image into LibreOffice Impress. For this image I would like to apply rounded corners. Does LibreOffice Impress provide a tool to change the corners of an inserted image?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Rounded corners idea]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can give to an image the shape you like by:

1. insert image
2. Create shape that you want to give to the image, and put it above the image
3. Select both objects
4. Right-click on them, "shapes" -> "intersect"

There you go.

Using this approach you can have rounded corners or whatever other shape you like.

See screenshots:
[image: menu]
[image: result]

Comment: How to select both object ?

Comment: Image proportions become distorted for me after this. Is it a bug or some other way exists?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this has not been possible before, and according to relevant documentation there are no such feature in LibreOffice.

You probably need to use a 3rd party software to apply rounded edges.

However, based of my knowledge this is achievable in the current OpenOffice. You might want to give it a shot :)

Comment: Thank you! Isn't OpenOffice [dead](http://i.imgur.com/bSkMh4s.png)?

Comment: You can prepare the image with rounded corners in GIMP

Comment: It is EOL but I still use it sometimes. Got some handy functions :) @orschiro

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it's worth submitting a feature request for LO?